# How do I capture a double-click in DragonRuby Game Toolkit?

Tags: dragonruby-game-toolkit

I've noticed in [the documentation for mouse clicks](http://docs.dragonruby.org.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/#-----args-inputs-mouse-click--or---down-----previous_click-----up-) that there is a `mouse.click` and `mouse.previous_click`; how do I need to structure my input handling code in order to be able to tell someone has double clicked?

I've tried this but am wondering if there's something I'm missing in the toolkit that will let me capture this in a way that's less fine-tuned than hoping someone clicks faster than 300ms.

```rb
def defaults(args)
  args.state.mouse_queue ||= []
end

def input(args)
  if args.inputs.mouse.click
    args.state.mouse_queue << args.inputs.mouse.click
    if args.state.mouse_queue.size == 2
      if args.state.mouse_queue[1].created_at - args.state.mouse_queue[0].created_at < 20
        # my double click handling code here
      end
      args.state.mouse_queue = []
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Double clicks are rarely used in games.

The reasoning is a click means something, fire, zoom... whatever, and the reaction is expected immediately (current step or next), making the detection delay for a double click action a very long time to wait for a single click response for most games.

> I've tried this but am wondering if there's something I'm missing in the toolkit that will let me capture this in a way that's less fine-tuned than hoping someone clicks faster than 300ms.

Most gamer double clicks are 30-60 ms apart, for a regular person 35 - 100 ms is the norm. For the slower settings, this range is extended to 200 ms and beyond depending on OS settings.

A 300ms, almost 1/3 of a second, window is more than ample time for the slowest double click, especially if you have a single click action.(forcing a greater than .3s minimum delay between consecutive actions.)

Comment: Sorry - while this is helpful context, it doesn't quite capture "how do I do this idiomatically in this tool?". An easy example of a place double clicks are used in games would be the pattern in strategy games of "double click this unit to select all of this unit on the screen" - while I agree the pattern isn't common, other than finetuning my milliseconds number this doesn't answer the question if there is something within DragonRuby to do this that I have missed.

Comment: @girasquid "if there is something within DragonRuby to do this that I have missed."  No, I do not think you missed anything intrinsic, not that I could find. Given the question, I answered the best I could to help others later on. I apologize.

Comment: Aaah no apologies needed! Still helpful context, I appreciate you sharing it. :)